# org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionElement type "listners" must be declared

Tags: selenium

Getting following error in eclipse"

> 1.The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors| 
>   suite-files)*)".

2.If run erroneous testng.xml following error is thrown:

> org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>   4; columnNumber: 11; Element type "listners" must be declared.

Comment: provide your testng.xml code and your listersclass and how used in tests

Comment: it will helps you https://www.guru99.com/listeners-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: As I see You have element called "listners" and should be "listeners", missing letter "e" after "list"

Answer (score 0):

To call a listener, we need to mention it in the testng.xml with the proper listener tag

Ex:

```
<listeners>
        <listener class-name="TestNgListners.CustmoListner"/>
    </listeners>
```

The custom listner is created under the location "TestNgListners.CustmoListner"